# How to add a div element to an "aocolumn" of a datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

How to add the progressBarDiv to the status column of a datatable. Inside the status column, I'm trying to display the progressbar. How can I achieve this?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue...

My html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="progressBarDiv"></div>
<script>
    var currentPath = null;
       var options = {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
             "sScrollY":"250px",
          "fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
        var path = aData.Path;
        $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
            $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
                table.fnClearTable();
                table.fnAddData(data);
                currentPath = path;
            });


            $.get('/directory?path='+ path).then(function(data){        
                $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);

             });         
            e.preventDefault();
            });
        },
        "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"File Name", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  if (data.IsDirectory) {
                    return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
                  } else {
                    return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
                  }
                }
              },
                {"sTitle":"Date",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "75px",
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  if (data.IsDirectory) {
                     return  data.Date;
                 }else{
                   return data.Date;

                 } 
                }
              },


            {"sTitle":"Status",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "55px",
                "render":socket.on( 'message',   function (data, type, row, meta) {

                        console.log(data);

                  if (data.IsDirectory) {
                     return data.percent;
                 }else{
                   return data.percent;

                 }
                })

              }
            ]   
         };
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){})

      var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable(options);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it your intention to have every row in the table have the exact same value on the progressBar? I'm guessing that what you want here is to show a different "progress value" for each row. Either way, I think you need to define your progress bar on a per-row basis rather than trying to render the same progress bar into every row. Perhaps you could clarify your intentions a bit and explain why you want the same div in multiple rows (which I don't think is possible or advisable, especially since that div has an id attribute defined which should be unique in the document).

Comment: yes,I'm trying to keep different progress bar value  in each row correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

if the aoColumns render attributes are working for you, I'd recommend that you continue using those. Be sure to give each progress bar a unique ID, perhaps with a naming convention similar to "progressBar".